# Killing orphan IEs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, internet-explorer-8

I have an application in which many IE applications are opened. When I close my application some orphan IE processes are left in the task manager. I want to kill all the orphan IE processes without affecting other IE windows opened outside my application. 
I tried finding all IE processes and killing all processes which have their window handle 0 or window title null but by doing this IE crashes. Please help me out

Comment: That depends on how you opened IE to begin with. Are you sure this isn't a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346533/how-to-close-internet-explorer-when-it-has-been-ran-with-process-start

Comment: Actually in my application some IEs are opened using the shDocvw and some IEs are opened by starting a new process.

Comment: I tried process.close() and process.closemainwindow() but the processes does not stop. And by killing the processes the IE crashes