# Detecting selection of a string

Tags: c#, string, events, selection, detection

Is it possible to detect string selection in any application?
I need to write some application which would be run in the background and it would be checked if any string is selected (for example in some website content or in PDF reader or in Word). If some string selection would be detected it should be copied to clipboard.

Comment: You mean a routine that checks if the user makes a selection with the mouse, in any running application, no matter what kind? No.

Comment: It's not possible in managed language due to strict memory boundaries. But you can do it if you implement the code as a driver in C.

Comment: see here for a possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665045/how-to-get-the-word-under-the-cursor-in-windows/