# Programmatically read current text selected in console window

Tags: python, windows, powershell, winapi

I have built an app which receives text input from the user in a command prompt. And I would like to allow the user to select text and use that text instead of requiring the user to type it in.

**In linux/bash this is achieved by calling "xsel"** (a bash utility) which outputs the currently selected text which I then pipe to my python script. In windows it seems there isn't a simple solution... Any idea how do I get currently selected command line text in python/batch/powershell/external utility in Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: The simple solution is `Read-Host`. It'll prompt the user for input. Assigning the input to a variable makes it easier to work with as well. `$var = Read-host -Prompt 'what ya want'`, the input is saved to `$var`.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala will it be using the mouse?

Comment: In the typical console.exe enable Quick Edit.  That makes it much easier to select copy then paste. Which, when combined with Read-Host, I think is very close to the request.

Comment: No, you would have to make a selection to choose from. There is an option to use the arrow keys using `$host.ui` but, that's a little more difficult to understand coming from a different cli.

Comment: You can run my script/function here: https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/4908-delete-userprofile. It's a good example on how you can make a selection from sub directories in *C:\Users* which then, prompts you to delete a single, or multiple profiles. Same logic can be applied to a lot of other things

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the word under the cursor in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665045/how-to-get-the-word-under-the-cursor-in-windows)

Comment: @SimonMourier It might just be, but it is in C# and it's not clear to me if the automation class used there will be available for a regular script (and not in a testing scenario)?

Comment: Hey @Steven, looks interesting, but please could you elaborate? What is Read-Host ? is it a powershell command? and how does it work?

Comment: UI Automation is the Windows API technology. Powershell supports inline C# or you can simply build an exe from C#.

Comment: Thanks, Steven. @SimonMourier, please see the footnote I've just added to my answer for why I think your proposed solution won't work in this particular scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I'm assuming you're only interested in text selected *in the current console window*.

There is no **perfect solution on Windows** that I'm aware of<sup>[1]</sup>, but **you can *approximate* one**, which, however, ***requires the user's cooperation*, in the form *right-clicking*** after making a selection.

The solution below works in both regular console windows (`conhost.exe`) and Windows Terminal:

- In regular console windows, "Quick Edit" mode should be enabled, so as to allow direct selection of text with the mouse.
- To make the solution work, the user must *copy the selection to the clipboard*, which later allows you to retrieve the clipboard's content if no direct input was supplied. This is easily achieve by *right-clicking* (anywhere inside the window) after making a selection, which the prompt message must instruct the user to do.

Here's an example:

```
# Since the selection can only be obtained via the clipboard and we don't want preexisting
# clipboard content to interfere with the operation, we clear the clipboard first.
Set-Clipboard '' 

# Define the prompt string to use with Read-Host containing instructions.
$prompt = @'
Enter a value and press Enter 
 - OR -
Select a string in this console window, RIGHT-CLICK and then press Enter
'@

# Prompt for user input until it is non-blank, either by direct input or via the selection.
do {
  $userInput = Read-Host $prompt
  if (-not $userInput) { # No direct input, try to get the selection from the clipboard.
    $userInput = Get-Clipboard
  }
} while (-not $userInput.Trim())

Write-Verbose -Verbose @"
You entered or selected:

  «$userInput»

"@
```

---

<sup>[1] While (non-PowerShell-friendly) techniques exist *in principle* to **query a Windows console's selection** (involving the - "softly" deprecated - [`GetConsoleSelectionInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsoleselectioninfo) WinAPI function), or, more generally the cross-application Windows Accessibility API that allows "spying on" UIs, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4734275/45375)), these techniques cannot be used by code that directly, synchronously executes in the console window itself, because **typing or submitting a command invariably involves automatic *clearing* of the selection *before* returning control to the shell / a running porgram**. In regular console windows - but not in Windows Terminal - the first <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress after having made a selection actually copies the selection to the clipboard and *then* clears the selection and returns control to the shell / running program, so that pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> *twice* instead of right-clicking and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> works too.

Terminals on **macOS** also clear the selection first.

By contrast, on **Linux** at least **X-Window-based terminals *retain* the selection** in this case (as verified with the Gnome Terminal that ships with Ubuntu 18.04), which, as your question suggests, **can be combined with the (installable on demand) `xsel` utility** to programmatically query the selection.</sup>

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @rubmz. The footnote I've added explains the challenges that prevent a better solution. There may be a way to overcome them, but it would require substantial effort.

Comment: I am not looking for a perfect solution. Clearing the selection is a problem on Linux too, I guess in any terminal. But it's suffice for my application. Thanks again! This was a harder issue to tackle than I thought it would be :-)

Comment: @rubmz, yeah, it seems like there should be a simpler solution. The only terminal that does _not_ clear the selection when the shell / a program running in the shell regains controls is the Gnome Terminal that comes with Ubuntu, so using `xsel` (must be installed on demand) indeed works there; my guess is that all X-Windows-based terminals behave this way.

Comment: @IInspectable, you left out half of that sentence: "_We do not recommend using this content in new products_, but we will continue to support existing usages for the indefinite future." The term _deprecation_ is ambiguous: it can either refer to functionality _that will be removed in a future version_  or to functionality _that isn't recommended for new projects anymore_ but will be kept for backward compatibility. An informal way to refer to the latter form of deprecation is to call it "soft", and I've updated the footnote accordingly.